# Run CMake Install target with incredibuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake, incredibuild

I am trying to use incredibuild to speed up the compilation of a cmake project in command line, compiling with Visual Studio 2013.
I am able to compile and install the libraries by using the command:

```
BuildConsole zlib.sln /prj=INSTALL /cfg="Debug|x64"
```

But it skips the install part:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.40629.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
```

However, if I execute it from Visual Studio, it works fine:

```
Initializing...

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.40629.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 1/6/2016 4:52:09 PM.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because     "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>PostBuildEvent:
1>  -- Install configuration: "Debug"
1>-- Installing: C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/lib/zlibd.lib
1>-- Installing: C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/bin/zlibd.dll
1>-- Installing: C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/lib/zlibstaticd.lib
1>-- Installing:     C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/include/zconf.h
1>-- Installing: C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/include/zlib.h
1>-- Installing: C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/share/man/man3/zlib.3
1>-- Installing: C:/work/dev/workspace/thirdparty/tmp/install/zlib/share/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
1>  ...
1>  
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\INSTALL.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.40
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any clue ?

Thanks !
Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

This reply is from the IncrediBuild team:
We have downloaded and tried the same build of zlib-1.2.8 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 in our lab.
We've found out that by default in zlib, when using cmake to generate the .sln and .vcxproj files, the generated INSTALL project was NOT included in the build configuration "Debug|x64".
When building the generated zlib.sln for "Debug|x64", it does not build the INSTALL project, not via VS IDE and neither via the BuildConsole command - which is fine, since the project was not included in the build configuration.
Once the INSTALL project is marked as selected to build in the "Debug|x64"
configuration, there is no issue of it being skipped and the project is built correctly.
Either choosing to explicitly build this project for "Debug|x64" or fixing the zlib cmake to include this project to be built in "Debug|x64" fixes the issue.

Disclaimer: the writer is an IncrediBuild employee

Comment: Bug in zlib? Have you filed it or provided a patch?

Comment: I don't believe this is an appropriate fix as CMAKE does not support generating a solution with INSTALL already set to selected, and we must regenerate our CMAKE often, while this is happening on a build server. The point of a build server is largely lost when someone has to go and manually log in and recheck a check box for every time cmake regenerates

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is first run MSBuild on the solution, then on the Install.vcxproj individually. This is completely unrelated to IncrediBuild though, I'm using just plain MSBuild. I suppose IncrediBuild can be used on the solution, then MSBuild on the Install project.

Actually, in my case (without IncrediBuild) just running MSBuild on the Install.vcxproj is enough, it detects the dependencies and builds the other projects before the Install project.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing the same with incredibuild. I wonder why MSBuild does not do the same as the VS UI where building the install project does everything.